# Refresh token in Desktop App for OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow

Tags: winforms, oauth-2.0, jwt, oauth-refresh-token

I want to use API in my .net WinForms application which are closed by JWT token. Such tokens can be received from the Identity Provider using Authorization Code Flow + PKCE. I worked with such flow before in Web Application and I know how to request code, exchange it on the access token and I used silent refresh approach to refresh the access tokens.
For my clientId I'm not able to use refresh tokens. So, I'm slightly confused how to implement to refresh tokens in the Winforms application.
It's definitely I need to open Login page to allow the customer enter credentials. Then I guess I need to catch code from the Redirect URL. It seems I need to use loopback IP address as a redirect URL and catch request in the application.
But how to set up refreshing process I have no idea. Please help with advice or add links to examples.

Answer (score 1):

For a desktop app  you should follow the recommendations from [RFC8252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252). Without a token refresh you will get usability problems. Eg access token expires after 15 or 30 minutes, then user experiences a re-opening of the system browser.

This might be fine for a high security app, such as for banking, but for most apps it is not what you want. Alternatives such as long lived access tokens are bad from a security viewpoint, since the long lived value is then exposed on every API request.

You won't be able to use silent renew via hidden iframes either, since you don't have that much control over the system browser. You can only open it by executing a URL.

So you have these main choices, and maybe you can explain trade offs to stakeholders. You won't be able to implement a workaround in code:

- No refresh token, and sub-optimal usability
- Refresh token used, so a longer lived API credential is used in a public client

Locking down what can be done with an access token issued to the desktop app - using scopes and claims - is usually the main mitigation of this type of security concern.